# Correct structure for a Django application and handling the views and sub views

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I struggle a bit in order to understand how a Django Application should be properly structured. In particular, I struggle to get my head around the views.

So I have this file

```
base.html
```

And I know that this file will have common elements of the whole application such as footer, navbar, head etc.

So far so good.
Inside my `base.html` file I will have the tag:

```
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

Which handles the dynamic content of the application.
Now I create a static page called `home.html` and inside that file I put

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
... Whatever I want
{% block content %}
```

And now comes the part that I really struggle to understand how it works.
I create a new app called `dashboard`. I create a `dashboard.html` file and similarly to `home.html` I extend the base, and but elements inside the `content block`. In the `views.py` of the generated application I define:

```
@login_required(login_url="login/")
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, "dashboard.html")
```

and the `dashboard.html`

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="dashboard-page">
        <div class="row equal-sides">
            <div class="col-sm-2 trim-right">
                {% include 'dashboard_navigation.html' %}
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10 trim-left">
                <div class="dashboard-main card">
                   <h3>Welcome to your dashboard</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

[image]

Happy days. Now I want to reload only the main container on the right-hand-side, depending on the selection from the navigation bar on the left-hand-side. How do I achieve that?

I thought that if I will add a new url inside my urls file and a corresponding view inside `views.py` file it will be all good.

```
def single_search(request):
    tweets = get_tweets()
    context = {'tweets': tweets}
    return render(request, "search.html", context)
```

`urls.py`

```
url(r'^dashboard', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
url(r'^dashboard/search$', views.single_search, name='search'),
```

However, what I get is the same page as the `dashboard.html`
[image]

I managed to go around the problem and display "proper" content with the following code:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %}
    <div class="dashboard-page">
        <div class="row equal-sides">
            <div class="col-sm-2 trim-right">
                {% include 'dashboard_navigation.html' %}
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10 trim-left">
                <div class="dashboard-main card">

                    {% if 'search' in request.path %}
                        {% include 'search.html' %}
                    {% else %}
                        <h3>Welcome to your dashboard</h3>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> {% endblock %}
```

But I know that it is not the proper way of doing it. I also know that the context that I am passing is not being returned due to the fact that it is inside the `include 'search.html'` tag. If I pass the same context inside the dashboard it works both in the `search.html` and `dashboard.html` unfortunately I only want to see that content in if the user is on the `search.html` subpage.

Additionally, I append the tree of my application:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is simply that you haven't terminated your dashboard URL pattern, so it matches both URLs. It should be:

```
url(r'^dashboard$', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
```

If you find regexes confusing, the new `path` syntax in Django 2.0 might be easier.

Comment: For clarification purposes: Django goes down the list of possible views until it finds a regex that matches the provided URL. Once it does that it stops searching and sends you to that view. It would have actually worked if you had your `search` view placed before your `dashboard` view in your URL list simply because it would have found `search` first. Doing as Daniel pointed out is best-practice to ensure order isn't the deciding factor in your view routing.

Comment: Holy Cow! Many Thanks, Daniel! Your solution has fixed my problem.